# How to create percentage image

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and I just made a simple voting poll. It works and shows the percentage for each question (there are 3 questions in total), but I want also to show a bar that shows the percentage as well (so if the first question is 50% and the bar is 100px, the bar for that question should be 50px).

Here are the vars that have the final number (percentage).

> $fr = round(($f / $total) * 100);
>       $sr = round(($s / $total) * 100);
>       $tr = round(($t / $total) * 100);

Comment: Any particular reason to use an image instead of HTML?

Comment: Knowing what all those vars represent could help a bit...

Comment: Anything is fine, as long as it sets a definite size of the bar and then shrinks it to the percentage of each question.

Comment: @Dzumla you have to use `jquery` for styling dynamically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for an image, but this is easily accomplished in HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100px">
    <div style="background-color:#F00;width=50%">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! I modified this a bit and of course used the PHP vars but this basically saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Others have posted this already, but I was coding a sample and decided to post it anyway

Live Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/vG6jy/4/

**CSS**

```
.bar{
    height:16px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #999;   
    margin:15px;
    background: #b3bead;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b3bead 0%, #dfe5d7 60%, #fcfff4 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b3bead), color-stop(60%,#dfe5d7), color-stop(100%,#fcfff4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b3bead 0%,#dfe5d7 60%,#fcfff4 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b3bead 0%,#dfe5d7 60%,#fcfff4 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b3bead 0%,#dfe5d7 60%,#fcfff4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b3bead 0%,#dfe5d7 60%,#fcfff4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3bead', endColorstr='#fcfff4',GradientType=0 );
}
.bar .value{
    height:100%;
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 );  
}  ​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:0%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:25%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:50%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:75%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:100%;"></div>
</div>
​
```

**PHP**

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="value" style="width:<?php echo $fr; ?>%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MihaiIorga: In that case, why not simply use CSS3 animations? :)

Comment: @MihaiIorga: Nice! PS - Doesn't IE lack in support for CSS3 Animations? I like this jQuery Method

Comment: @Dutchie432 that's pure JS, here is CSS3: http://jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/MCnMU/, but <IE10 lack of animations.

Comment: Right - that comment was directed at `Madara Uchiha`. The `nice` was directed at you.

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating this.

```
<div class="meter">
    <span class="percentage" style="width: 25%"></span>
</div>


.meter { width: 150px; border 2px solid #666; }
.percentage { background-color: #00FF00; }
```

Comment: so put it inline. no one is stopping him.